# NODE_OPTIONS='--insecure-http-parser' not being used with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

One of the web services my lambda connects to is periodically returning an invalid HTTP header and causing Node to throw with this error.

We are running lambda with the NodeJS 12.x runtime.

```
"name": "RequestError",
    "message": "Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char",
    "cause": {
        "bytesParsed": ,
        "code": "HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN",
        ....
```

Following the instructions from this [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27711#issuecomment-584621376) it looks like the fix for 12.X would be to either use `--insecure-http-parser` or `--http-parser=legacy` as an option to starting Node.

Passing `insecureHTTPParser` to `http.request()` is not an option since we are using a http abstraction.

On Lambda the documented way to pass CLI options to use is to use the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable which is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-modify.html)

So I've tried setting either `--insecure-http-parser` or `--http-parser=legacy` and spawning a new lambda invocation and I'm still getting the `HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN` error.

Here's a screenshot of my Environment Variables in lambda.

[image: env variables]

Upgrading the NodeJS runtime is not an option too.

My high level question is how can I make this work?

Some other useful information in the comments would be

1. How can I verify that NODE_OPTIONS passed to Lambda in an environment variable are actually set at runtime?
2. How can I verify what HTTP parser is configured to be used in Node 12.x?

Comment: Which HTTP abstraction are you using? Some abstractions, like `node-fetch` and `axios` will pass `insecureHTTPParser` through to `http.request()`.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for the answer Sam, I'm working with some pretty old code here and we've used https://github.com/request/request-promise-native in this part of the code. I couldn't figure out how to pass that down to http.request(). Would be super happy if you know a way to.

Comment: Switching out the HTTP abstraction here isn't really an ideal situation but it is something that I could do as a last resort.

Comment: Looking through the source of `request` (`request-promise-native` wraps it), it seems to also pass `insecureHTTPParser` through even though it isn't listed in the types on `@types/request`.